# how to add a Restful service(another project) to ServiceRoute in WCF 4.0?

Tags: wcf, rest

I used wcf 4.0 rest template to generate a project A and build my service class in another project B. So my question is hot to add this service in Global_asax.

This code is working if I put myservice class in project A.

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add(New ServiceRoute("RestService", 
                      New WebServiceHostFactory(),
                      Type.GetType("ProjectA.myservice")))
```

But if I put myservice in project B, following code does not work.

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add(New ServiceRoute("RestService", 
                      New WebServiceHostFactory(), 
                      Type.GetType("ProjectB.myservice")))
```

Answer (score 1):

First, it would make it easier for people to help you solve yur problem if you posted the details of the exception your getting. That said, I have an idea of what is happening here and it likey has nothing to do with WCF.

You're not specifying enough information to `Type.GetType` for it to be able to be able to find your ProjectB class. This is most likey because the ProjectA you're referring to is the ASP.NET application itself and so when you only specify the namespace.classname it's able to find it because it's in the same assembly. To find a class in another assembly, you need to include it in the call to `type.GetType` like so:

```
Type.GetType("ProjectB.ClassName, ProjectBAssemblyName")
```

Finally, perhaps you're simplifying the example, but I have to ask why you aren't just using typeof here instead of dynamically loading a hardcoded dependency like that.